# Multiple .Where() clauses on an Entity Framework Queryable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to implement a complex filter using Entity Framework: I want to add `where` clauses to the queryable object based on my provided search criteria.

Can I do the following in Entity Framework 6?

```
var queryable = db.Users.Where(x => x.Enabled && !x.Deleted);
// Filter
var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
queryable.Where(x => x.AspNetUser.Id == userId);
queryable.Where(x => x.Status >= 2); 
// ...etc
```

I know that I can do:

```
var queryable = db.Users
 .Where(x => x.Enabled && !x.Deleted)
 .Where(x => x.AspNetUser.Id == userId)
 .Where(x => x.Status >= 2);
```

But I am not getting the expected results with this solution. It seems to be ignoring the seconds two `where` clauses.

Comment: You need to assign the result, something like: `queryable = queryable.Where(x => x.AspNetUser.Id == userId);` By the way, you can use `and (&&)` and avoid writing multiple `where` clauses.

Comment: @Akbari, that should be an answer

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`.Where` returns a queryable, it does not modify the original. So you just need to save the new queryable.

```
var queryable = db.Users.Where(x => x.Enabled && !x.Deleted);
// Filter
var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
queryable = queryable.Where(x => x.AspNetUser.Id == userId);
queryable = queryable.Where(x => x.Status >= 2); 
// ...etc
```

Comment: That's fine, but builds an AND clause.  It's not quite straightforward to create multiple OR conditions.

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you are trying is runtime search. If that is the case you have two options.

1. Using expressions to build a run time where clause. You may have to use a predicate builder. [This](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) predicate builder may not work with Entity Framework. But [this one](https://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/) should work with entity framework.
2. Using [Dynamic Linq](http://dynamiclinq.azurewebsites.net/). This by far the easiest. Its very versatile. Not only can you do Where, it supports select and order by and others as well runtime quite easily!!! Do take a look.